# What does `Encoder.SaveFlag` do?

Tags: .net, image, bitmap, system.drawing.imaging

`Encoder.SaveFlag` is one of the `EncoderParameter` variants which can be used when saving a bitmap to a file, stream, etc.

This parameter IS documented but the documentation says essentially nothing about what it is for, despite even using it in an example.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.saveflag

In the example, the parameter is first used in this snippet:

```
// Create an Encoder object based on the GUID
// for the SaveFlag parameter category.
myEncoder = Encoder.SaveFlag;
```

(Note that the comment actually says nothing meaningfully useful to understand the intent - it really just restates the code).

It is then used while creating several new new `EncoderParameter()` objects, but again without actual explanation.

Thanks

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384173/what-does-encoder-scanmethod-do

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384078/what-does-encoder-version-do

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384129/what-does-encoder-rendermethod-do